# Android:Default Action bar is populating while loading App

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Android-When my android app is launching populates default action bar for seconds and then replaces that action bar with my customize action bar. How to get rid of that default action bar when my app is launching

Used Following Code To hide default Action Bar.Which eventually replaces my actual action bar

MainActvity.java

```
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_custom_view_home);
```

Android Menifest Code:

```
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
     android:name="com.example.demowithoutactionbar.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Show your AndroidManifest code, just to check theme you have used

Comment: How did you solved this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Try using this in your theme present in styles.xml 

`<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>`

Comment: Try applying the action bar changes before you setContentView() method and then as @maaz said! Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're styling your action bar or handling your launcher (some code samples might be helpful here), but you can prevent the Action Bar from showing on your launcher activity by specifying this in the manifest:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Thnx @mike For ur reply...But What is my concern is that  i can able to hide Default Action Bar but it is taking some seconds to hide and replacing with ma customize action bar....So while ma app is loading First its showing default Action bar for seconds and den it is showing ma actual action bar...u can take a look at above code which i hv used to hide ma default action bar...is it the correct way to hide default action bar or can u suggest sm other way to hide the same...thnx